# How to adjust mat dialog width in angular using css?

Tags: css, angular, sass, less, mat-dialog

How to adjust mat dialog width in angular using css ?  Increase modal size probably around width: 70vw and add a minimum width in pixels.

## math dialog or modal container

```
.mat-dialog-container {
    display: block;
    padding: 24px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: inherit;
    max-height: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add ***important*** to your css:

```
.mat-dialog-container {
    width: 300px !important;
}
```

This overwrites the default width from angular!